# Cant install any packages

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

I cant install any packages using apt install .
Im getting the following error

```
  sudo apt-get install mysql-server
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree
  Reading state information... Done
  E: Unable to locate package mysql-server
```

when i do apt-get update

```
# apt-get update
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [1,539 B]
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
    Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [1,548 B]
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
    Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [1,547 B]
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
    Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu main InRelease [1,537 B]
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu main InRelease
    Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Get:5 http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/newton InRelease [1,554 B]
Err:5 http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/newton InRelease
    Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Fetched 7,725 B in 0s (13.5 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: Can't drop privileges for downloading as file '/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/main/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/newton/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Before this i tried to uninstall mysql and i followed this

```
apt-get --yes purge mysql-server mysql-client
apt-get --yes autoremove --purge
apt-get autoclean
deluser --remove-home mysql
delgroup mysql
rm -rf /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/mysql /etc/apparmor.d/cache/usr.sbin.mysqld /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql /var/log/mysql* /var/log/upstart/mysql.log* /var/run/mysqld
updatedb
```

After this only im getting this error.Please help me resolve this.

Comment: Are you working under a proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you don't have internet access during this attempt. Try to ping google.com or go to the internet and if you can then try to run again. I have had issues with internet access after waking up my laptop from sleep, so I would at least try "systemctl restart networking".

It may also be worth checking to see if the /boot/ partition is full. Run "df -h" and see how much space is available there.

I know my answer might sound a bit silly, but you cannot forget to check the basics before trying to update/upgrade/install packages.